# How do i choose the most optimal turbine (Style, pitch, size...) for a very small scale Hydropower project?

Tags: energy-efficiency, turbines, renewable-energy, hydrodynamics

I have a project in which I am designing a lightweight, portable hydropower system, and I'm unsure of how exactly I am to choose the correct style of turbine. For context, the turbine is only really going to be used in a 'Run-of River' style, in areas with a flow rate between 1.0 m/s and 4.0 m/s. It's something I haven't really worked on before, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Speed is not the only concern.

You need to consider the mass flow rate, but I don't think you have the flow rate of the hydro scheme local to me: 75m^3 per second through 3 Pelton turbines with a head of 1883 metres.

You need to work out whether a Pelton, Francis or Kaplan turbine will work for your situation.

From a small scale setup we generated 3.5kW with a flow rate of 20 litres/sec and some 30 metres head.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, although this is a bit of an ambitious project, i am trying to see what kind of power I can generate with a head of max 1 metre in an area with flow rate roughly 45kg/s. Having been given the constraints of lightweight and portable, I've been pushed towards designing a turbine which is only about 15cm in diameter.